python how to annotate type "functiontype" to function?
How to annotate ruturn type or attribute type "functiontype"?
expectations:
def _(function: functiontype) -> functiontype:
   return function

The type() used on any function returns <class 'function'>. The question is, where to import <class 'function'> from.

The additional question is, why, while the function keyword is enlightened, it is not shadowed by naming variables like that?

You can import FunctionType from the types module, but you almost certainly don't want to restrict the argument to one specific type of callable. FunctionType is specifically for user-defined functions (defined with def or a lambda expression), and excludes built-in functions like sum.

The <class 'function'> is just a string representation for debugging, it's not the actual value (which is an object of class type)

@JiříBaum We can assume OP is referring to the value whose __repr__ produces that string, not the string itself.

@chepner I mean, a local variable wouldn't shadow it because the __repr__ wouldn't be referring to local variables at all

As for where it is defined, it claims to be from builtins but the builtins module doesn't export it; one would be going into the internals of Python to find where it's defined, or if it can be imported — it's not something that's directly used in the vast majority of Python code

For type hints, functions can be annotated using collections.abc.Callable or typing.Callable
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callable-objects
For example, Callable[[int], str] signifies a function that takes a single parameter of type int and returns a str.
